# Overflow flexbox width issues in css cannot figure it out when resizing

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow

I have been trying to figure out how to fix this problem all day.

It happens when resizing the window to a smaller size.

Picture explaining what I want to achieve:

[image: Picture explaining what I want to achieve]

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9ac2ke22/1/

```
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #F2994A;  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #F2C94C, #F2994A);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #F2C94C, #F2994A); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
}
.header {
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black
}
.boxcontainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.box{
  min-width: 400px;
  width: 60%;
  background-color: red;
}
.picture {
  display: inline-block;
}
.text {
  display: inline-block
}
img {
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
}
```

I have tried over a million combinations of css attributes with a million combinations of properties.

to name some things:

word wrap, max-width and overflow-hidden (this kills it even more)

Can someone please help me figure this out.

Comment: min-width:400px is in the way and also you should allow flex children to wrap . To read,  again if you did   https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Could be point out on what element i should apply min-width, since I already use it but it doesn't work, nevermind just read that i need to wrap the children too.

Comment: I meant that your min-width was in the way below 400px, not that it was missing somewhere ;). hope you fixed it. BR